# Clipped Button XML

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

I have the following XML layout;

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/found_item_catnum_name"
        style="@style/qi_head_name_bubbles"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/catalog_number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/found_item_catnum_value"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/found_item_catnum_name"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/found_item_catnum_name"
        style="@style/qi_head_val_bubbles" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/found_item_committed_name"
        android:layout_below="@id/found_item_catnum_name"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/found_item_catnum_name"
        style="@style/qi_head_name_bubbles"
        android:text="@string/committed2customer" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/found_item_committed_val"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/found_item_committed_name"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/found_item_committed_name"
        style="@style/qi_head_val_bubbles" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/found_item_stock_name"
        android:layout_below="@id/found_item_committed_name"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/found_item_committed_name"
        style="@style/qi_head_name_bubbles"
        android:text="@string/available_stock"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/found_item_stock_value"
        style="@style/qi_head_val_bubbles"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/found_item_stock_name"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/found_item_stock_name"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/medium_margin" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/expand_stock_button"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/search_btn_dim"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/search_btn_dim"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/found_item_stock_value"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/found_item_stock_value"
        android:background="@drawable/add_button"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The button defined at the end of the layout has its bottom edge clipped, as seen in the Eclipse graphic layout rendering image:
[image: Clipped button]

I really can't understand what is causing the clipping.  The parent layout's border is not doing it, as shown by the blue border added by the rendering tool. Any clue would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a margin   eg:`android:layout_marginBottom="10dp`

```
 <Button 
        android:id="@+id/expand_stock_button"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/search_btn_dim"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/search_btn_dim"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/found_item_stock_value"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/found_item_stock_value"
         android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/add_button"/>
```